What does the author implies by saying "by way of being a hint"?
I tried to find the accurate phrase but unfortunately, I could not. This is the whole context:

That does not mean, however, that the bond market rules the world in the sense that James Carville meant. Indeed, the kind of discipline he associated with the bond market in the 1990s has been conspicuous by its absence under President Clinton’s successor, George W. Bush. Just months before President Bush’s election, on 7 September 2000, the National Debt Clock in New York’s Times Square was shut down. On that day it read as follows: ‘Our national debt: $5,676,989,904,887. Your family share: $73,733.’ After three years of budget surpluses, both candidates for the presidency were talking as if paying off the national debt was a viable project. According to CNN
Democratic presidential nominee Al Gore has outlined a plan that he says would eliminate the debt by 2012. Senior economic advisers to Texas Governor and Republican presidential candidate George W. Bush agree with the principle of paying down the debt but have not committed to a specific date for eliminating it.
That lack of commitment on the latter candidate’s part was by way of being a hint.

Ferguson, Niall. The Ascent of Money: A Financial History of the World: 10th Anniversary Edition (English Edition) (p. 109). Penguin Publishing Group. Edición de Kindle.
I found in the Farlex Idioms and Slang Dictionary the phrase "by way of (something)" which is defined in its second sense this way:

As a method or means of doing something. When Paul arrived 30 minutes late, he complained about the traffic by way of explanation.

International, Farlex. The Farlex Idioms and Slang Dictionary: The Most Complete Collection of Idioms and Slang in the English Language (Posición en Kindle19062-19063). Farlex International. Edición de Kindle.
I think this is the intended sense for this particular context, implying that this lack of commitment was a hint that they would not abide by the rules. Is this correct?

Yes, your understanding is correct.

"Was by way of being" is a long-winded, jokey way of saying "was".

It's downright flatulent. Or should I say "outright flatulence"?

I wonder, on reflection, if it is not so much jokey as just bad writing, although the two are not mutually exclusive.

The pattern you found isn't typical these days. You found a definition that will be more useful most of the time, as more uses will look something like "'That was unfortunate' was all he offered by way of an apology."
The example you found here, "[to be] by way of [being something]", is, according to this blog, an older colloquial usage that was chiefly British, and isn't common today.
